# A known event to a history junkie

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I rhyme with a word that could stand for a country -
A known event to a history junkie,
A weird relation to modern computers
I share beginning with angry refuters.

What am I?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A wild guess, but...

> Defenestration

I rhyme with a word that could stand for a country -

> Rhymes with "nation"

A known event to a history junkie,

> [The Defenestration of Prague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defenestrations_of_Prague)

A weird relation to modern computers

> Defenestration means throwing people out of **Windows**

I share beginning with angry refuters.

> Defense?  Defenders?  Not sure on this one. Deniers (as in Climate ...)

Comment: Oooh I like this a lot, hat tip for the Thirty Years’ War reference! +1

Comment: This is where my mind went as well. +1 :D

Comment: Correct answer! Nice job! Only the last line needs a little clarification.

Comment: Perhaps the last line is referring to rot13(qrsraqnagf/qrsrafr nggbearlf va n pbheg pnfr)?

Comment: @PiIsNot3 I was thinking of rot13(12 Natel Zra), but that was the rot13(whel) not the rot13(qrsraqnagf)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, I was thinking rot13(natel ershgref ersre gb qravref), but your explanation also fits. Marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: May be rot13(qrsvref) or rot13(qravref).

Comment: Okay, I guess I was trying to match too many letters at the beginning - your expected answer only had 2 to my 5...

Answer (score 4):

I rhyme with a word that could stand for a country -

> revolution rhymes (partially) with nation which is synonymous with country

A known event to a history junkie,

> there were several prominent *revolutions* in the world history

A weird relation to modern computers

> computer revolution: https://www.encyclopedia.com/history/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/computer-revolution

I share beginning with angry refuters.

> shares beginning with *revolters* (or perhaps revolutionaries)

Comment: This is a great answer, although I question how closely your answer rhymes with the word you proposed. +1.

Comment: I don't think you need to be a history *junkie* to know at least a few of these.

Comment: A good answer, but it is not the answer.

Answer (score 4):

> [Antikythera?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism)

I rhyme with a word that could stand for a country -

> Inglaterra, which is England in Spanish. Got this one from a rhyming dictionary, I don't know how Antikythera is actually pronounced.

A known event to a history junkie,

> Antikythera mechanism is an Ancient Greek artifact

A weird relation to modern computers

> It's considered an extremely early version of an analogue computer

I share beginning with angry refuters.

> "Anti" as a prefix seems to fit this

Comment: This doesn't seem like an *event*, but it does seem to match a lot of the checkboxes.

Comment: Another good word, but not the answer.